# NamError: Name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

**If I try to run this script I'm getting an error "NamError: Name 'self' is not defined", please help me resolve this issue I'm new to Python. I tried to resolve this by reading different sources but it didn't work.**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import argparse

# Values that are required to calculate the signature. These values should
# never change.
DATE = "11111111"
SERVICE = "ses"
MESSAGE = "SendRawEmail"
TERMINAL = "aws4_request"
VERSION = 0x04

def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def calculateKey(secretAccessKey, region):
    signature = sign(("AWS4" + secretAccessKey).encode('utf-8'), DATE)
    signature = sign(signature, region)
    signature = sign(signature, SERVICE)
    signature = sign(signature, TERMINAL)
    signature = sign(signature, MESSAGE)
    signatureAndVersion = bytes([VERSION]) + signature
    smtpPassword = base64.b64encode(signatureAndVersion)
    print(smtpPassword.decode('utf-8'))

def main(self):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Convert a Secret Access Key for an IAM user to an SMTP password.')
    parser.add_argument('--secret')
    help='my_access_id_here',
    required=True,
    action="store"
    parser.add_argument('--region')
    help='us-west-2',
    required=True,
    choices=['us-east-1','us-west-2','eu-west-1'],
    action="store"
    args = parser.parse_args()

    calculateKey(args.secret,args.region)

main(self)
```

Comment: Replace `def main(self)` by `def main()` and call it with `main()`

Comment: I rolled back the question to its original state, as the edits made had changed the code by removing the parts that caused the problem, which made the question completely pointless. Note to the editors: never change the code in the question. If something is wrong - which is why the question exists in the first place - it has to be dealt with in the answers.

Comment: It didn't work, I tried to remove this and start but came with another error. Can anyone try to run this and see if they able to run it properly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove self from your main() as self is required only when its a class method, regular functions don't have self as first argument.

Quote from documentation:

> Often, the first argument of a method is called self. This is nothing more than a convention: the name self has absolutely no special meaning to Python.

see below doc for more info

[documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks)